# How to set the textfield is not visible in frame

Tags: java, swing, visibility

I am using Swing framework, and I have one question.

The Address panel is dynamically added to the main frame.  I want to call the `visible(false)` method from the main frame on the Address Panel.

Comment: please add some code to show context and indicate what you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is store the `JTextField` as a private member of the `AddressPanel`.  And, in `AddressPanel`, add a method called `hideTextField()`.  Then, in that method call the `setVisible(false)` method on the private `JTextField` member.

The code may look similar to the following:

```
public class AddressPanel {

    private JTextField textFieldToHide;

    public void hideTextField(){
        textFieldToHide.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Then, in the main frame use it like so:

```
addressPanel.hideTextField();
```