# How to make JTextField (Eclipse Window Builder) read only

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I want to make my `JTextfield` invisible and read only but the value must be shown in a window frame. I am using window builder in Eclipse.

```
JLabel lblLabel1 = new JLabel("Default DITA-OT File :");
lblLabel1.setBounds(10, 79, 123, 14);
frmPdfPublisher.getContentPane().add(lblLabel1);

JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
separator.setBounds(10, 140, 414, 2);
frmPdfPublisher.getContentPane().add(separator);

JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
separator_1.setBounds(10, 257, 414, 2);
frmPdfPublisher.getContentPane().add(separator_1);

textField_1 = new JTextField();
textField_1.setBounds(138, 76, 286, 20);
frmPdfPublisher.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
textField_1.setColumns(10);
textField_1.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: try this solution in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081713/how-to-set-the-textfield-is-not-visible-in-frame)

Comment: @DataPro I can set visible and invisible . But will that show any values? Values showld be visble . Ex :- Like we see on right click-> properties-> file location. ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). ..

Comment: .. 3) *".. the value should be visible in Eclipse"* What? The value should be invisible to the user but visible in your IDE? The text of the question suggests you want that the user type in one window, but the value be visible in another. Please [edit] the question and clarify what is actually required.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Done Thank You

Comment: @DarkV1  read only value with no background borders etc . I already did it yesterday.

Comment: @RohitGhosh remember to accept an answer when you have what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make it read only than `JLable` is better option to do this work .

However if you want to use `JTextfield` than make text field as a private member and use a method to settext field hidden .

```
class Example {

private JTextField tf;

public void hideTextField(){
    tf.setVisible(false);
} }
```

Change the color of Textfield and make it same As color of Panel or frame .

```
setBackground(Color.white);
```

And Remove Border Either by overriding setBorder method or by Passing "null" to

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white));

or

txt.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.white,0));
```

Comment: I can do that , but i want to make my value visibile in it , which is not happening.

Comment: this code is not showing value visible . It is invisible too.

Comment: @RohitGhosh , Change the Background Color of Text field and make it same as color of Panel or Frame .

Comment: Simply Remove the border .

Comment: I made changes in my answer , Please Check .